# Why my app everytime crashing, errors not found, code font big?

Tags: android

This is the problem: I'm writing an application, there was a need to add a navigation drawer. Found a third-party support library. Wrote the code, no errors, but after installation the application crashes. Help!  I've tried different libraries, but it's not working. If necessary, I'll provide other files.

**MainActivity**

```
package... 

import... 

public class MainActivity extends DrawerActivity
{




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.e("idi", "nahui");
        addProfile(
            new DrawerProfile()
            .setRoundedAvatar((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_app_icon))
            .setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snackbar_background))
            .setName(getString(R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description))
            .setDescription("HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT")
            .setOnProfileClickListener(new DrawerProfile.OnProfileClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DrawerProfile drawerProfile, long id)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked profile #" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        );
        addItem(
            new DrawerItem()
            .setImage(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio))
            .setTextPrimary("First")

            .setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItem.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DrawerItem drawerItem, long id, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked first item #" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        );
        addDivider();
        addItem(
            new DrawerItem()
            .setImage(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_star))
            .setTextPrimary("Second")
            .setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItem.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DrawerItem drawerItem, long id, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked second item #" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        );
    }

}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: ... 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.+.+'
    compile 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-drawer:2.3.3'
}
```

**LogCat**

```
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: net.aaaps.webdesignlearning, PID: 19062
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.aaaps.webdesignlearning/net.aaaps.webdesignlearning.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3047)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1777)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:450)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at net.aaaps.webdesignlearning.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7110)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7101)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2922)
11-08 01:27:33.717 19062 19062 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 9 more
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: net.aaaps.webdesignlearning, PID: 19421
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.aaaps.webdesignlearning/net.aaaps.webdesignlearning.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3047)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1777)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:450)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at net.aaaps.webdesignlearning.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7110)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7101)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2922)
11-08 01:28:28.301 19421 19421 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 9 more
11-08 01:29:01.300 19991 19991 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 01:29:01.300 19991 19991 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: net.aaaps.webdesignlearning, PID: 19991
11-08 01:29:01.300 19991 19991 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.aaaps.webdesignlearning/net.aaaps.webdesignlearning.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-08 01:29:01.300 19991 19991 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
11-08 01:29:01.300 19991 19991 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3047)
11-08 01:29:01.300 19991 19991 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file ?

Comment: Do you know the SDK version of the phone?

Comment: This is the biggest clue 'You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.' - This bug involves support for older code/phones. What does your 'DrawerActivity' extend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: I wrote this theme in the manifest, the error does not go away.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line in your crash log that point you to the problem:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity.

You need to set your activity to use Theme.AppCompat in your manifest file.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Why the negative review?